# How do I recombine unwinded documents?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have the following document:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5881cfa62189aa40268b458a"),
    "description" : "Document A",
    "companies" : [ 
        {"code" : "0001"}, 
        {"code" : "0002"}, 
        {"code" : "0003"}
    ]
}
```

I want to filter the `companies` array to remove some objects based on the `code` field.

I've tried to use unwind and then match to filter out the companies, but I don't know how to recombine the objects. Is there another way of doing this?

Here's what I've tried so far:

```
db.getCollection('test').aggregate([
    {
        $unwind: {
            'path': '$companies'
        }
    },
    {
        $match: {
            'companies.code': {$in: ['0001', '0003']}
        }
    }
    // How do I merge them back into a single document?
]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better way would be to just use the [$filter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/index.html) operator on the array.

```
db.getCollection('test').aggregate([
    {
     $project: 
       {
         companies: {
             $filter: { 
                  input: '$companies', 
                  as: 'company', 
                  cond: {$in: ['$$company.code', ['0001', '0003']]}
             } 
         }
       }
    }
])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) and control the document structure like that but its tedious work as you have to specify each and every field you want to preserve.

I recommend instead of unwinding to use [$filter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) to match the companies like so:

```
db.getCollection('test').aggregate([
    {
        $addFields: {
            companies: {
                $filter: {
                    input: "$companies",
                    as: "company",
                    cond: {$in: ["$$company.code", ['0001', '0003']]}
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {  // we now need this match as documents with no matched companies might exist
        $match: {
            "companies.0": {$exists: true}
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: I am not sure whether we need the $match stage here, I guess OP just wants to filter companies array.

Comment: We do need it if we want consistent results as OP does `{$match: {'companies.code': {$in: ['0001', '0003']}}}`

Comment: Because OP first used $unwind,  when $filter is used it does not make sense to use $match.

Comment: `$filter` alone worked. I originally attempted using match after unwind to remove the company objects that I did not want. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep the way you are doing using Aggregation pipeline:

```
db.getCollection('testcol').aggregate([     
    {$unwind: {'path': '$companies'}},
    {$match: {'companies.code': {$in: ['0001', '0003']}}},     
    {$group: {_id: "$_id", description: { "$first": "$description" } , "companies": { $push: "$companies" }}} ,

])
```

Comment: Thank you! I ended up with `$filter` but your answer helped me learn.